# CSS can I transition to flex-end?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, transition

I'm trying to add a transition property to a checkbox switch. It's start position is flex-start and I want it to transition smoothly to flex-end. I just don't seem to be able to make it work on the flex-end property, yet bizarrely, the switch moves to flex-end and the background color transitions correctly.

I have looked at previous answers to problems similar to this, but I just can't crack this nut!

Can someone please let me know what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

```css
/* the container controls the switch size */
.switch-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  background-color: coral;
}

/* hide the default checkbox */
.checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

/* target the label i.e. box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* target the span element */
.slider {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* set size of slider track */
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  /* === end set size === */
  background-color: #ccc;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  transition: var(--transition);
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  background-color: rgb(199, 36, 36);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px cadetblue inset, -2px -2px cadetblue inset;
  transition: var(--transition);
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translateX(129%);
  background-color: darkgreen;
  transition: var(--transition);
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196f3;
  transition: var(--transition);
}
```

```html
<section class="switch-container">
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
        <span class="slider"></span>
      </label>
    </section>
</html>
```

The problem I have is that If I make the switch size responsive to the size of the parent container, then using `transform: translateX(some-value)` to move the toggle slider the `(some-value)` has to be re-calculated to accommodate the current track size.

Comment: hello fishbite what you want exactly when u click it move with transition smootly right ?

Comment: the `align-items` property takes discrete value, you can not use the transition property on it

Comment: Hope this will help you [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp)

Comment: @KiranMistry yes I want it to transition smoothly right to the end of the track. My objective is to make the switch completely responsive in size for a game I am making. The problem with ```transform: translateX(26px);``` is that it is using a specific px value, which I don't want to use.

Comment: @meine are saying that I have no option than to use ```transform: translateX(some-value);```

Comment: @Fishbite just write `transform: translateX(100%);` instead of `transform: translateX(26px);` and it will work fine. i tried it and it is working great.

Comment: @Blaze_droid if use  I ```transform: translateX(100%);``` it stops short of the end of the track and I have to use ```transform: translateX(129%);``` on the current size of the element. If you got  ```transform: translateX(100%);``` to move to the end of the track, please show me what I'm missing. Thanks :)

Comment: Probably offsetting it by the checkbox width in some way might help (using `calc()`) … can’t quickly test it though, because you are messing up the snippets with your constant edits.

Comment: @Fishbite why are you making the snippets non-runnable?

Comment: @TJ appologies, making the snippets non-runnable wasn't intentional. Not sure what happened

Comment: @Fishbite. You surrounded the snippets with a _```_ string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot animate such values. I suggest, you animate margin-left instead

```
.switch {
  --slider-width: 26px;
  --switch-width: calc(100% - var(--slider-width) / 2);
  /* --- */
  width: var(--switch-width);
  /* --- */
}
/* --- */
.slider:before {
  /* --- */
  width: var(--slider-width);
  /* --- */
}
/* --- */
input:checked + .slider {
  margin-left: calc(var(--switch-width) - var(--slider-width) / 2);
}
```

```css
.checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

/* target the label i.e. box around the slider */
.switch {
  --slider-width: 26px;
  --switch-width: calc(100% - var(--slider-width) / 2);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: var(--switch-width);
  height: 34px;
}

/* target the span element */
.slider {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* set size of slider track */
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  /* === end set size === */
  background-color: #ccc;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: var(--slider-width);
  background-color: rgb(199, 36, 36);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px cadetblue inset, -2px -2px cadetblue inset;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  /* transform: translateX(125%); */ /* note this transitions correctly */
  background-color: darkgreen;
  /* transition: var(--transition); */
  transition: 0.5s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196f3;
  margin-left: calc(var(--switch-width) - var(--slider-width) / 2);
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to get across that the switch width is dependent on the users' device size and thus is an unknown value

Comment: @Fishbite You changed your code significantly after my answer

Comment: apologies again, I was working on editing my code and hadn't seen that you had posted before I committed the changes

Comment: I've edited my code. It's just a matter of getting the right calulcations

Comment: I think that was my problem, I couldn't figure out how to calculate it as you have shown. This works and I marked it as the correct answer. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my try for this.

```css
/* the container controls the switch size */
.switch-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  background-color: coral;
  --transition: 300ms
}

/* hide the default checkbox */
.checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

/* target the label i.e. box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* target the span element */
.slider {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* set size of slider track */
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  /* === end set size === */
  background-color: #ccc;
  align-items: center;
  transition: var(--transition);
}

.slider:before {
  content: "";
  flex: 0;
  transition: var(--transition);
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  flex: 1 1 0%
}

.slider:after {
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  background-color: rgb(199, 36, 36);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px cadetblue inset, -2px -2px cadetblue inset;
  transition: var(--transition);
}

input:checked + .slider:after {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  transition: var(--transition);
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196f3;
  transition: var(--transition);
}
```

```html
<section class="switch-container">
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
    <span class="slider"></span>
  </label>
</section>
```

Comment: Well, that does exactly what I wanted to do and doesn't mess with the design :) I really need to look into this ```flex: 1 1 0%``` as I'm not certain how it's doing what it's doing!!! Am I right in thinking it's a flex-grow property? Your input is really appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome @Fishbite. And that's correct, I used flex-grow property :)